# Spring boot 2.5.1 @AutoConfigureMockMvc doesn't load RouterFunctionMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I've upgraded my spring boot from version 2.3.3 to version 2.5.1 and it causes a test with

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

configuration to fail with 404 instead of 200

After comparing the logs what I found out that before the upgrade log contained the mapping:

```
2021-07-19 21:00:48.881  INFO 15114 --- [    Test worker] o.s.w.s.f.support.RouterFunctionMapping  : Mapped /api => {
  (GET && /ping) -> org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RouterFunctionDslKt$sam$org_springframework_web_servlet_function_HandlerFunction$0@22cf59c1
}
```

and after the upgrade, I couldn't find any RouterFunctionMapping log, so I guess it's probably related.
If it helps I defined the router using Kotlins RouterFunctionDsl.

I've tried looking for other questions and even to look for breaking changes, but I couldn't find any hint.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't think that MockMvc would work with WebFlux. Perhaps you need WebTestClient?

Comment: OK, seems like it didn't print anything because the info log was replaced by a debug log, any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems that the problem is that for some reason, it can't find the endpoint unless I add a trailing slash to the mockMvc.perform call, very weird.